# Can’t get VO2 Max (Cardio Fitness) measurements to work on Apple Watch Series 7

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

I can’t get my Apple Watch to show up as a data source for Cardio Fitness measurements in the Health app, no matter what I try. I’ve tried everything in this article and nothing has worked: https://www.myhealthyapple.com/is-your-apple-watch-cardio-fitness-vo2-max-not-showing-any-data-lets-fix-it/

Is there anything else I can try to get Cardio Fitness to work?

Comment: Have you restarted both devices? does the watch communicate other data?

Comment: Yes, I’ve restarted both devices and the Watch communicates heart rate, respiratory rate, workouts, and other data.

Comment: Cardio Fitness is not something that shows up immediately. Per Apple "It can take at least 24 hours wearing your Apple Watch, followed by several workouts* and passive measurements with your Apple Watch before you receive an initial estimate."

Comment: I’ve had my Apple Watch for several months now and still nothing.